# How to put Bootstrap ValidationMessageFor in correct position?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, validation, message

I am using bootstrap for my web application, and I have problem with validationmessagefor puting message state in correct position. Now I have use this example from this [link](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html?#forms), with this code:

```
<div class="control-group error">
  <label class="control-label" for="inputError">Input with error</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input type="text" id="inputError">
    <span class="help-inline">Please correct the error</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now code that I use:

```
<h4 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h4>
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">                 
        @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Username, new {placeholder="Username", @class="form-control username", id="inputError"}) 
        <span class="help-inner">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Username)</span>                        
    </div>

    <div class="controls">       
        @Html.PasswordFor(u => u.Password, new {placeholder="Password", @class="form-control password"}) 
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u=> u.Password)
    </div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
```

My code do this (also in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4h5E5/1/):

[image]

But my disire is to put validate message in this position (like example in link):

[image]

Comment: Use CSS to position it. Simple way i can think right now is you can do float:right;

Comment: interesting, but it put only in end of right side of input (e.g. username)

Comment: So you want it on right side as you have shown in fig

Comment: Yes -Richa, i have in my style.css put beside float: right, margin-right and margin-top, and it puts in correct position, but responsive not work ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check this [JS Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/devangkantharia/E8Nk8/)

> HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form class="form-signin form-horizontal" role="form">
             <h4 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h4>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7">
                    <input type="username" class="form-control username" placeholder="Username" required="autofocus" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-5"> <span class="help-inline pull-left">Please correct the error</span>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control password" placeholder="Password" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-5"> <span class="help-inline pull-left">Please correct the error</span>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7">
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <!-- /container -->
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript==================================================- ->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
</body>
```

I hope this is what you want to achieve.

If you have any other issue or if not solved, then please add a comment below.

Regards D.

Comment: Yes it works, but it shrink my input fields?? Did you make any changes in css?

Comment: ok, i figure out, changes were in css also. Thanks man!!!! It works, you are the best!

Comment: Yes, if you want to increase with width of inputs, then change the wrapper width, that is, `.form-signin {max-width: 600px;}`

Comment: I need more something, how to put singing form in the middle of screen. If you can see, it puts it in left of screen. Now is input and error in middle. I need only singing form in middle.

Comment: If you want to show everything in middle, then I suggest you to show the error message as a tooltip instead of using the layout structure as shown above. Please refer to this [JS Fiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/devangkantharia/E8Nk8/7/). The layout was shifted to left because of the `col-xs-7 col-sm-7` classes. Tooltip is the preferable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this? (untested)

```
  <div class="controls">
    <input type="text" id="inputError" class="pull-left">
    <span class="help-inline pull-left">Please correct the error</span>
  </div>
```

ps.would be great if you make a fiddle.

Comment: it is the same ... here I have create fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4h5E5/1/ (also posted in question)

Answer (score 1):

Use `style = "display:inline"` for  `EditorFor` and `ValidationMessageFor` both, as below:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2"})

    <div class="col-md-9">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", style = "display:inline" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName, "*", new { @class = "text-danger", style = "display:inline" })
    </div>

</div>
```